# Formset Data Initialization

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to understand how the initialization of formset data works. To create a formset you use formset_factory and define arguments "extra" and "max_num", which determine the number of extra blank forms after the initial/filled forms and the max number of forms posted respectfully. But then, when you create an instance of the defined formset to pass to the template as data, you pass into that instance more data, specifically 'form-TOTAL_FORMS', 'form-INITIAL_FORMS', and 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS'. But haven't we already defined in the formset_factory the max_num_forms? Why are we defining this twice? For documentation initial forms seems to be just what it sounds--forms already filled in, which is different than "extra". Just don't understand defining the max arg twice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> You may have noticed the additional data (form-TOTAL_FORMS,
> form-INITIAL_FORMS and form-MAX_NUM_FORMS) that was required in the
> formset’s data above. This data is required for the ManagementForm.
> This form is used by the formset to manage the collection of forms
> contained in the formset. If you don’t provide this management data,
> an exception will be raised.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Comment: Yeah I understand they're necessary--and I get why MAX_NUM_FORMS needs to be available as an argument passed through the template. My question is: why do we have to reiterate the maximum number of forms in the variable form-MAX_NUM_FORMS when we have already specified this piece of data in formset_factory? For instance, what happens if I define "max_num"=5 in formset_factory, but then define form-MAX_NUM_FORMS = 10 when creating a formset instance?